# import discord indentationerror: unexpected indent

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

Hello I am using heroku for hosting my discord.py not but I am getting errors in the logs and my botvis not getting online
You can check my github repo at
https://github.com/reyyan987/organic
Discord.py

```
    import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime

from urllib import parse, request
import re

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', description="This is a Helper Bot")

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

@bot.command()
async def sum(ctx, numOne: int, numTwo: int):
    await ctx.send(numOne + numTwo)

@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.guild.name}", description="Lorem Ipsum asdasd", timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), color=discord.Color.blue())
    embed.add_field(name="Server created at", value=f"{ctx.guild.created_at}")
    embed.add_field(name="Server Owner", value=f"{ctx.guild.owner}")
    embed.add_field(name="Server Region", value=f"{ctx.guild.region}")
    embed.add_field(name="Server ID", value=f"{ctx.guild.id}")
    # embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{ctx.guild.icon}")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://pluralsight.imgix.net/paths/python-7be70baaac.png")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def youtube(ctx, *, search):
    query_string = parse.urlencode({'search_query': search})
    html_content = request.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string)
    # print(html_content.read().decode())
    search_results = re.findall('href=\"\\/watch\\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
    print(search_results)
    # I will put just the first result, you can loop the response to show more results
    await ctx.send('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + search_results[0])

# Events
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="Tutorials", url="http://www.twitch.tv/accountname"))
    print('My Ready is Body')


@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):
    if "tutorial" in message.content.lower():
        # in this case don't respond with the word "Tutorial" or you will call the on_message event recursively
        await message.channel.send('This is that you want http://youtube.com/fazttech')
        await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run(os.getenv('Token'))
```

You can check other files at my github respoitry
My logs

```
2021-02-26T08:21:20.856803+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python filename.py`
2021-02-26T08:21:21.541356+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-02-26T08:21:24.270010+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-26T08:21:24.340039+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-02-26T08:21:24.201416+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "filename.py", line 2
2021-02-26T08:21:24.201450+00:00 app[worker.1]:     import discord
2021-02-26T08:21:24.201450+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ^
2021-02-26T08:21:24.201451+00:00 app[worker.1]: IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Please use the [tag:botframework] tag only if you're using the Microsoft Bot Framework

Answer (score -1):

I just remove the spaces before import discord it work but I'm getting this error in logs now

```
2021-02-26T14:34:44.743738+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-02-26T14:34:44.743770+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "filename.py", line 54, in <module>
2021-02-26T14:34:44.743897+00:00 app[worker.1]:     bot.run(os.getenv('Token'))
2021-02-26T14:34:44.743920+00:00 app[worker.1]: NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

Comment: Youre not importing `os` in the code you provider, nor in the github repo. Simply import it. Please think a bit, you should ask on stackoverflow if you can't find any solution, a simple google search would solve this issue

Comment: Oh so I need to import is to my Code too

Comment: well yeah you used it in your last line, are you copying the code from somewhere or what?